# Android - using parsed xml data to update SQLite

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing

just a reminder that I'm a noob so maybe my question is fairly stupid...

Anyway I'm using SAX to parse an XML file and I can correctly loop through the items and print their contents to the log. What I'd need though is for this parser to return a multidimensional associative array that I can iterate through and subsequently use to update an SQLite database...

**Question(s):**
Does such a thing exist in Android? Should I be using some other datatype instead? How is it done?

I'll include some code of the parser (the endElement method does the printing to log, so far it has one element per item but that will change, hence the need for multidimensional):

```
private boolean in_image = false;
private boolean in_homeimage = false;
StringBuilder sb;

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

        for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++) {
            sb.append(ch[i]);
        }

    //super.characters(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if( localName.equals("image") && this.in_homeimage ){
        this.in_homeimage = false;
        Log.i("Extra", "Found homeimage: " + sb);
    }
    else if( localName.equals("image") ){
        this.in_image = false;
        Log.i("Extra", "Found image: " + sb);
    }

    //super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    sb = new StringBuilder();

    if( localName.equals("image") && attributes.getValue("name") == "home" )
        this.in_homeimage = true;
    else if( localName.equals("image") )
        this.in_image = true;

    //super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
}
```

Thanks in advance